# what is the best sizes for splash screen in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen, android-styles

I'm new in android development.

I use the theme in res/values folder to display splash screen:

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

in AndroidManifest I have:

```
<activity
            android:name="SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

splash screen's activity code is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private static final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME = 3000; /* 3 seconds */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

                SplashScreen.this.finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein,
                        R.anim.splashfadeout);
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME);
    }
}
```

and in res/drawable folder I have file launch_screen.png (480 * 800 px).

1) are my dimensions ok for the most of android devices?

2) may be I need to add some other images or styles files in other folder?

Thank you in advance?

Comment: Does it *have* to cover the entire screen? Why not just center without scaling? Also, does it *have* to be a splash screen? Since you're using a fixed timer, I'm assuming it isn't for loading, so it's really just an annoyance to users, no?

Comment: Do your users a favour.  Forget splash screens.  They are evil (Google it ;).  Best size for a splash screen is 0x0.

Comment: ok, I will remove it. Didn't know that it 's bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a picture that android can stretch to the current device screen. And if it a detailled filled picture, you will probably want to provide more than one in order to control the quality. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

By the way... Splash screens are bad ;) think if you can remove it and start directly.

Comment: may you can provide instruction in what folder to insert what image or style file? because for me it's difficult to understand google's instruction. it's better if you can provide px sizes. I need to support all the android devices.

Comment: Splash Screens can be good if only showed on the first app launch.